# Difference between simple storage pool and striped volume

Tags: disk-space, disk-management, storage-spaces

Is there any difference between using Windows Storage Spaces with Simple resilience (no resiliency) and striped volume in Windows Disk Management?

Comment: One key difference is that non-Storage Space disks in RAID configuration are *not* visible in the list of disks in Resource Monitor. Never really understood why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows Storage Spaces with Simple resilience [are striped](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/15200.storage-spaces-designing-for-performance.aspx) so you should get the same result.